# How to get ng-model value to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

in the following directive I need ng-model value.

```
  app.directive('getRelatedDocumentDetails',['documentService',function(documentService){


    return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'AE', //attribute or element
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope,element,attrs,ngModel){
                element.on('change',function(element,attrs){
            //Here I need ng-model
    })

            }
        }
```

In the above code I am not getting ng-model inside the change function.

Comment: please provide plunkr link..

Comment: the directive link takes these parameters: `scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn`. So your `ngModel` is just a controller. Get the values from the scope instead: `console.log(scope.my_value);`

Comment: As @AlekseySolovey mentined, ngModel is the ngModelController in this case. [Docs here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) If you want to update the ngModel value when element changed, use `$setViewValue`.

Answer (score 0):

The link function allows you to directly access the scope objects as you do in your controller.

So you can directly access the scope object used for `ng-model` here

Suppose you define html as below

```
<get-related-document-details ng-model="myVar">
</get-related-document-details>
```

Then code in the controller will be like

```
app.directive('getRelatedDocumentDetails',['documentService',function(documentService){


    return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'AE', //attribute or element
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope,element,attrs,ngModel){
                element.on('change',function(element,attrs){
            scope.myVar='something'; //here you can assign value to ng-model scope variable
    })

            }
        }
```

Comment: I doubt it works like that. In order to have `myVar` on scope, the directive needs to bind it to the isolated scope via `scope: {myVar: "=ngModel"}`